# How to keep media mail from showing up as a shipping method when non-media items purchased

Tags: shipping

Most of my inventory I sell is books, which I offer to ship through media mail.

However I recently started selling other products which aren't media related items. How do I set up Magento that when one purchases one of these non-media items, automatically media mail won't show up as an shipping option?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what media mail is, but If it's properly implemented in Magento there should be a method called `collectRates` in the shipping method model.
You need to change this method to return nothing in case you have non-media items in the cart.
The method `collectRates` receives a parameter called `$request`.

Here is how you can do it.

```
foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
    //$product = $item->getProduct(); //you can access the product entity if needed
    if (condition here to check if $item or $product is non-media) {
         //so if non-media
         return false;
    }
}
```